# Make HTTP request with Elixir and Phoenix

Tags: json, http, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm a Ruby dev trying to get into elixir. I'm trying to interact with an API in order to learn a little Elixir. I'm basically trying to make an http request. In ruby the thing I'm trying to do would look like this.

```
require 'httparty'


url = "https://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/2016/11/05/schedule.json?api_key={api_key}"
response = HTTParty.get(url)
req = response.parsed_response
```

Pretty straightforward and simple. Now I have a json decoded response that I can use. How can I do this with Elixir and Phoenix?

Comment: Have you tried searching for a library? https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison is the most popular one. With that, `HTTPoison.get(url)` should fetch the data.

Comment: Yea, I just found that. It looks great.

Comment: You can also look at https://github.com/myfreeweb/httpotion, if intereseted on knowing the difference and probably why you would not use them read this interesting article https://virviil.github.io/2018/04/06/elixir-do-you-have-http-requests-you-are-doing-them-wrong/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With [`httpoison`](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison) (HTTP Client) and [`poison`](https://github.com/devinus/poison) (JSON Encoder/Decoder) packages, this is almost as simple as your code which uses `HTTParty`:

```
url = "https://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/2016/11/05/schedule.json?api_key=#{api_key}"

response = HTTPoison.get!(url)
req = Poison.decode!(response.body)
```

Answer (score 23):

Not only can you write your code as simply as before as shown in [@Dogbert's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46638948/2066155), but you can do cool things with pattern matching, too (and be as granular as you like)

Using HTTPoison and Poison, as well:

```ex
url = "https://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/2016/11/05/schedule.json?api_key={api_key}"

case HTTPoison.get(url) do
  {:ok, %{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
    Poison.decode!(body)

  {:ok, %{status_code: 404}} ->
    # do something with a 404

  {:error, %{reason: reason}} ->
    # do something with an error
end
```